# CloudWatch Insights filter to only homepage requests including with query string

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

We have a field for "url" in our logs, and I'd like to be able to filter down to just requests hitting the homepage. This would be requests for `/` and for `/?*`, i.e. with any query string.

Just getting homepage requests is `| filter url = "/"` but how do you include those requests that have a query string also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html

Something like this should work:

```
filter url = "/" or url like /^\/\?.*/
```